# Залочить форму на время работы события

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Есть на форме кнопка сохранить. Когда я её нажимаю, есть необходимость залочить форму, и запустить например колесо прокрутки с текстом на подобии "Подождите идёт выполнение". Это не суть. Не разу такого не делал. Подозреваю что такое делается с помощью javascript. Подскажите пожалуйста как такое можно реализовать? Или возможно есть какие то примеры. Если есть подкиньте пожалуйста посмотреть как такое делают.

Comment: Лично я бы ничего не лочил. Достаточно пойти по пути модальных окон, затянуть весь экран полупрозрачным fixed контейнером с параметрами {width: 100%; height: 100%}, и далее, где угодно показывать ваше "колёсико". Соответственно, куда пользователь не ткнёт - ему помешает контейнер, который "заберёт" клик на себя.

Comment: Вот, как это может выглядеть визуально (из нашего проекта): https://i.gyazo.com/1453933f9e8001a10f7872a42ca65527.png Всё что выглядит "тёмно-серым" - это задний план, сообщение с обработчиком - это передний план. Между ними полупрозрачный чёрный контейнер.

Comment: @test123 да, примерно так и реализовал уже. Спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: @test123 не подскажите ещё как можно создать чат и пригласить туда любого участника для обсуждения. Очень нужно но не разу этого не делал.

Comment: Прокрутите сайт вниз. На тёмном фоне футера будет одна из ссылок "Чат" https://i.gyazo.com/0c2581c53171648d6821340da6ef2c33.png Там внизу создайте новую комнату (Create new room), и скинте человеку, которого хотите пригласить ссылку на вашу комнату.

Comment: @test123 благодарю за помощь.